# Building .ko module for different Kernel Headers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, compiling, git

I am trying to build the wil6210.ko module/driver for Ubuntu. I downloaded the source code from:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kvalo/ath.git/commit/?id=24a72b77f3407a9ac173aa6978f44106ed0742d7

However, this module is built for the Kernel version 4.12.0-rc6, whereas I want to integrate it in my machine which runs kernel version 4.4.0-87. I have read that this can be done by changing the kernel header files during the make process, but I am unable to figure out how that is done here.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It is unlikely that the module can be built against the 4.4 kernel without any modifications of the module code, if it is possible at all.

Comment: Isn't it already built into kernel version 4.4.0-xx? Confirm: `modinfo wil6210`

Comment: No it wasn't. It is by default built into 4.12.0-rc6. But I decided to circumvent the problem by updating my kernel to the newer version. I am able to integrate the module into the kernel now without any issues!